# Do samples of radioactive materials in vaccum, produce ions and acquire net charges

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, radioactivity

Suppose an atom decays via a $\beta^-$ decay, it's atomic number has increased by one, and an electron is emitted.
$$
_Z^AX \quad \to \quad_{Z+1}^{\quad A}X'\ + \ _{-1}^{\ \ 0}e^- \ + \ \bar v _e
$$
here a neutron turns into a proton emitting an *electron* and an *electron - anti neutrino*. The electron has velocity that is a fraction of the speed of light, and travels away from the influence of the daughter nuclei.
Now the daughter nuclei has $Z+1$ protons and $Z$ electrons, making it a **positive ion** of a new element.
Similar pondering will suggest a $\beta^+$ decay of an atom will make a **negetive ion** of some new element.
similarly for $\alpha$ decay we have a **negetive ion** with 2 more electrons than protons (in symbolic form, $_{Z-2}^{A-4}X'^{\ \ \mathbf {2-}}$).

---

Now if we have a sample of a pure radioisotope that decays via $\beta^-$ decay in vaccum, as time passes and atoms decay we should observe that the sample becomes richer in positively charged protons, and deficient in electrons, thus acquiring a net positive charge. Similarly other in types of decay (exept $\gamma$ decay) we should have samples acquiring net negetive charges.

---

Now to the Questions:

1. Is the above reasoning correct? Do samples of radioactive materials produce ions and acquire net charges
2. If 1) is not correct then what happens to samples radioactive *atoms* kept in a isolated system in vaccum?.
3. Has anyone actually performed such an experiment that you know of?

Comment: To answer some of your questions in a very concrete way, I advise you to do a search for "self powered neutron detector"  .

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/184474/44126), [related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/338389/44126).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you are also creating extra protons (Z+1), so the net charge in the system remains the same.

You are creating extra negative electrons, but in a closed system they will recombine with positively charged ions.